# What exactly is happening under the hood in Normalized colour mapping in matlpotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, normalize

I had to make a bar chart of the means of 4 different distributions with error bars in matplotlib where the colours of the bars would change interactively depending on the given Y (mean) value. I used 1.96 for a 95% confidence interval.

```
stderr = df.std(axis=1)/np.sqrt(n)
norm = Normalize(vmin=-1.96,vmax=1.96)
cmap = get_cmap('PuOr')
Z = (mean.values -y)/stderr.values
normed = norm(Z)
```

This ensures that the code works as intended. What I would like to know is what exactly is going on when the values in Z:

```
array([-1.11052123,  2.98511452,  1.0731187 ,  9.30156312])
```

are getting mapped to the values in normed:

```
masked_array(data=[0.21670377, 1.26150881, 0.77375477, 2.87284774],
         mask=False,
   fill_value=1e+20)
```

How exactly is it being mapped? I know from reading the documentation that the values are being mapped to the interval -1.96 to 1.96. What I'd like to know is how exactly 9.30 is mapped to 2.87.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the norm is just a linear transformation that maps vmin to 0 and vmax to 1.  The values outside that range are mapped via the same linear transformation.

When calculating a color, the input values for `cmap` are considered to be between 0 and 1. If a value larger than 1 is encountered, it is simply mapped to the highest color.

Here is some code and plot to illustrate the behavior:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=-1.96, vmax=1.96)
Z = np.array([-1.11052123, 2.98511452, 1.0731187, 9.30156312])
zs = np.linspace(-3, 10, 50)

plt.imshow(np.linspace(-0.3, 3.2, 200).reshape(-1, 1), extent=[-3, -2.8, -0.3, 3.2], origin='lower',
           cmap='PuOr', vmin=0, vmax=1, aspect='auto')
plt.scatter(zs, norm(zs), c=zs, norm=norm, cmap='PuOr')
plt.vlines(Z, -2, norm(Z), color='crimson', ls='--')
plt.hlines(norm(Z), -3, Z, color='crimson', ls='--')
plt.vlines([-1.96, 1.96], -2, [norm(-1.96), norm(1.96)], color='dodgerblue', ls='--')
plt.hlines([0, 1], -3, [-1.96, 1.96],  color='dodgerblue', ls='--')
plt.ylim(ymin=-0.3)
plt.margins(x=0, tight=True)
plt.xlabel('Z', size=16)
plt.ylabel('norm(Z)', size=16)
plt.show()
```

[image: illustrating plot]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a great explanation. I have a couple of questions with what youve shown if you dont mind answering.  Why use axhline instead of hlines? Is it just so you dont have to type in extra coordinates for the endpoint? And what exactly is the 'extent' argument doing in plt.imshow?

Comment: `hlines` moves the limits of the plot, so standard these lines won't touch the borders. Whether `hlines` or `axhline` is most appropriate depends on the circumstances. It is not so much the typing, but knowing which positions should be used and for the whole to be easily changed. Optimally, each parameter should only be changed in one single place and the plot should keep coming out as intended. (Unfortunately, my code doesn't follow that principle enough in the code above.).  The `extent=` parameter of `imshow` sets the start and end points in x and y direction of the image.